# Why are no other Stack Exchange sites listed when voting to close a Q as off-topic?

Tags: support, close-reasons

When endeavouring to recommend the closure of a question relating to a python programming problem, the only other site available for selection as more appropriate was this meta site. Is there no way to select one to add it in? Or at least could some common sites be added to the list, if it is static - eg space exploration, physics, stackoverflow, etc?

Images of series of screens:

[image: step 1]

[image: step 2]

[image: step 3]

Comment: I think only mods can migrate questions to other sites.

Comment: Not what I am asking.

Answer (score 5):

Currently we do not allow *automatic* migration of content to beta sites. Moving questions to or from a site whose scope is still evolving can be somewhat problematic; even worse if the destination site were to be later closed.

So early in a site's development, we prefer migrations to be a bit more hands-on. If you see a question that *needs* migrating, you should flag it for moderator attention.

Comment: That isn't answering the question. I'm not asking that I be able to transfer it, just that I suggest that it belongs on a specific other site. I can do this for meta, but not for any others, and few questions are meta questions

Comment: @Jeremy I don't see how this does not answer your question. Typically closing a question because it belongs somewhere else will move that question automatically. When sites are in beta, we do not allow that to happen. So under the close reason "this question belongs on another site", there are no other sites listed because we do not set up those migration paths during beta. You can only say for sure that a question is off topic for *your* site (the first option).

Comment: Because following this series of actions does NOT close the question it just RECOMMENDS the question for closure. If it works correctly, a vote will be added to the close button, the moderators will see it and be able to review it, and others can add their votes. But it is completely pointless to have an option saying it doesn't belong here, it belongs on another stack exchange site, if no other sites are listed! Once again, I'm not asking to be able to automatically move it to another site, I just want to do what the steps suggest I ought to be able to do - suggest it should be elsewhere

Comment: That's where you are wrong. It doesn't recommend it for closure, your vote is effective. It only takes five votes (none of them have to be mods) to close it. I don't see why we can't have this as part of flagging as opposed to close votes, though.